# Сравнение производительности QQuickItem и QQuickpaintedItem

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick

не нашел четкого сравнения двух этих методов рисования виджета.
Один способ это рисовать все в paint().
Другой способ - с применением opengl в updatePaintNode().
Хотелось бы, чтобы весь виджет был написан на с++, а на qml слое, он просто добавлялся. Говорят, что с updatePaintNode() будет более быстродейственнее, но мне надо еще выводить текст, а как это делать, я не нашел.

Пока что, виджет написан полностью на с++. Там есть анимация, QpropertyAnimation, которая довольно много отнимает в производительности  6-12% цп, поэтому я копая в сторону updatePaintNode().

1) можно ли выводить текст на виджете в updatePaintNode()?

2) будет ли прирост производительности?

Comment: 1) да, единственное надо учитывать, что этот вызов этого метода блокирует главный поток рендера и не стоит делать там долгие операции (типа чтения из файла) 2) Да будет, т.к. это именно рендер объектов, отрисовка будет происходить в отдельном потоке https://evileg.com/en/post/296/ Также если ваша анимация есть 6-12% современного ЦПУ, то это что-то не так) Если у вас основное приложение использует QGraphicsView, то можно попробовать установить вьюпортом QGLWidget / QOpenGLWidget

Comment: насчет производительности цпу, это при т.сказать пиковых нагрузках и в реальности затраты будут около процента. Как выводить текст в updatePaintNode?